# Cubic equation problem $\frac{x^3}{3}-x=k$

Tags: functions, cubics

The cubic function $\frac{{{x^3}}}{3} - x = k$ has three different roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ about the real number k. Let's call the minimum value of $|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|$ as $m$. FInd the value of $m^2$.

My approach is as follow

$\frac{{{x^3}}}{3} - x = k \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = \frac{{{x^3}}}{3} - x - k$

$f'\left( x \right) = {x^2} - 1 = 0$

Hence $x =  \pm 1$

$f\left( 1 \right) = \frac{1}{3} - 1 - k =  - \left( {k + \frac{2}{3}} \right)\& f\left( { - 1} \right) =  - \frac{1}{3} + 1 - k =  - \left( {k - \frac{2}{3}} \right)$

For real roots $f\left( 1 \right)f\left( { - 1} \right) < 0$

Therefore $ - \left( {k + \frac{2}{3}} \right) \times \left( { - \left( {k - \frac{2}{3}} \right)} \right) < 0$

$k \in \left( { - \frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}} \right)$

We know that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$

But how we will find the minimum values of the sum of the modulus of the roots.

Comment: Can the root be complex?

Comment: No that is why I have used $k \in \left( { - \frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}} \right)$

Comment: The condition was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: By using modulus at the end  we presume that the roots are real

Comment: Sum of the roots is zero and the product is 3k

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi I think what Asher is saying is that the problem never mentions that the three roots of the polynomial must be real, only that $k$ must be real. You've shown that, if the roots are real, then $-2/3<k<2/3$. However, if the roots are allowed to be complex, we can no longer assume this restriction on $k$, and the problem becomes more difficult.

Comment: Even we assume complex that what is the role of absolute values of the roots

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi For a complex number $z=a+bi$ it is a standard definition that $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Distance from the origin and all that. That is why others are asking about the possibility of complex roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint $\;-\;$ using $\,\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=-3\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
m^2 &= \left(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|\right)^2
\\ &= \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 + 2\left(|\alpha\beta|+|\beta\gamma|+|\gamma\alpha|\right)
\\ &= \cancel{\left(\alpha+\beta+\gamma\right)^2} - 2(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)+ 2\left(|\alpha\beta|+|\beta\gamma|+|\gamma\alpha|\right)
\\ &= 6 + 2\left(|\alpha\beta|+|\beta\gamma|+|\gamma\alpha|\right)
\\ &\ge 6 + 2\,|\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha|
\\ &= 12
\end{align}
$$

This gives a lower bound on $m^2\,$. To prove it's an actual minimum, it is enough to find a $k$ such that $|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma| = 2 \sqrt{3}\,$, which turns out not to be too hard.

Note: the above assumes the roots are real (per OP's comments), in order for $\,|\alpha|^2=\alpha^2\,$ to hold.

Comment: @Asher2211 What that part proves is (only) the lower bound $m^2 \ge 12$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. For $k=0$ the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is assuming that the question intends to ask that each of $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ must be real in addition to $k$. If they are allowed to be non-real, the situation is trickier.

The sum $|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|$ is preserved if $k$ is replaced by $-k$, so we can without loss of generality assume that $k<0$, so that there are two positive roots and one negative root. Let the positive roots be $\alpha>\beta$, and let $\alpha(k)$ and $\beta(k)$ represent the functions mapping $k$ to the largest root and to the second largest root of $x^3/3-x-k$, respectively. We seek to minimize $2\alpha(k)+2\beta(k)$.

See if you can do this via calculus, writing the derivative of $2\alpha(k)+2\beta(k)$ in terms of $\alpha(k)$, $\beta(k)$, and $k$. Then you only need to check the endpoints ($k=0$ and $k=-2/3$), and any places where the derivative may be $0$.

Comment: You may want to check what I did. Tracking the sum of two roots is unnecessarily complicated. If you modify accordingly I will delete my answer and upvote yours.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this is similar to another answer, except that by recognizing only one root needs to be tracked instead of the other two the calculation is simplified.*

First observe that if we reverse the sign of $k$ then all roots are also reversed in sign with no effect on the set of absolute values, thus no impact on the sum $|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|$. So we can cover all values of this sum by considering just the case where $k$ is nonpositive.

Then only one root is negative by Descartes' Rule of Signs. Calling that root $\alpha$ we then have

$|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|=-\alpha+\beta+\gamma$

$\color{blue}{=-2\alpha\because\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0}$

Thus find the nonpositive value of $k$ that minimizes the absolute value of the negative root $\alpha$. Given that $k=0$ gives $\alpha=-\sqrt3$ and $k<0$ must give $\alpha<-\sqrt3$ (why?), you then get your answer using the blue equation above.

Comment: Thanks @514, it worked perfectly!